# Write $p^2$ as $x^2+2y^2+3\times 2^z$ with $x,y,z$ nonnegative integers

Tags: nt.number-theory, prime-numbers, diophantine-equations

In April 2018, I noted that the first integer $n>1$ with $n^2\not\in\{x^2+2y^2+3\times 2^z:\ x,y,z=0,1,2,\ldots\}$ is $$5884015571=7\times17\times49445509.$$

**Question.** Is it true that for each prime $p$ we can write $p^2$ as $x^2+2y^2+3\times2^z$ with $x,y,z$ nonnegative integers?

I guess that this question has a positive answer. Your comments are welcome!

Comment: Out of curiosity, in what context did you discover this fact?

Comment: I think your form is suitable only for 2  to 29 , Try p=31

Comment: @zeraouliarafik $31^2 = 29^2 + 2 \cdot 6^2 + 3 \cdot 2^4 $.

Comment: OP put a related sequence online, https://oeis.org/A301472

Comment: The density of the 3-variable sequence seems fine to me but the question still feels like a smooth glass mountain. Do you see at this time any chance of climbing or even starting it?

Comment: I think all integer positive number greater than 1 can be written in your form